# How to use ruby's named parameters (keyword arguments) more ellegantly (no duplicated code)?

Tags: ruby, named-parameters

Many times when I use named parameter in ruby, I end up with real-life cases like this:
`calculate_multiplier( year: year, plant_location: plant_location, number_of_doors: number_of_doors, manufacturer: manufacturer )` (you get the pattern, many key-value pairs where the key and the variable name are the same).
Can I write that without duplicating the code? Something like:
`calculate_multiplier( :year, :plant_location, :number_of_doors, :manufacturer )`?

I thought about a solution like:

```
    class Object
      def to_np( caller_binding, *array ) # to named parameters
        np = Hash.new
        array.each\
        {
          | var |
          value = eval( "#{var}", caller_binding )
          if( value.is_a?( Hash ) )
            np.merge!( value )
          else
            np[ var ] = value
          end
        }
        return np
      end
    end

    class C
      def m( a:, **o )
        # do something
      end

      def m_wrapper
        # based on some logic contained in this method, we'll get:
        a = 'A'
        o = { x: 'X', y: 'Y' }

        # not that elegant I would say
        # m( a: a, **o )

        m( to_np( binding, :o, :a ) )
      end
    end

    puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION

    require 'benchmark'

    number = 1000000
    Benchmark.bm( 4 ) do |bm|
      bm.report( 'm_wrapper' ) { number.times { C.new.m_wrapper  } }
      bm.report( 'm        ' ) { number.times { C.new.m( a: 'A', x: 'X', y: 'Y' ) } }
    end
```

But the output shows me there's an efficiency penalty for my love for beauty :)

```
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
           user     system      total        real
m_wrapper 17.140000   0.030000  17.170000 ( 17.149647)
m          1.230000   0.000000   1.230000 (  1.238346)
```

Any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [`instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) and see if you can do something with that.

Comment: I appreciate your dilemma (and effort to solve it), but I doubt there's a performant solution for this. I would love to see something like ES6's property punning (`foo({ year, plantLocation, ... })`) in Ruby. Perhaps worth filing a feature request if it hasn't been done yet.

Comment: Why do you use named parameters than at all? In case there are too many cases when you end up writing this params means that you don't need them. Their main advantage is to unwrap hash, for instance `h = {a: 'A', b: 'B'}`, `def my_meth(a:, b:); end`, `my_meth(h)`. Whereas `h` is something that is not defined manually